# How to pass recordId from fsl mobile application to salesforce mobile application?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I've been trying to pass recordId from fsl app to salesforce app for a while now, I've tried various methods but still no luck can anyone share a thorough way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PASS THE RECORD ID FROM FSL TO SF APPLICATION:-

```
step 1: create aura application:
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="YOUR LWC NAME"/>
</aura:application>    

step 2: create vf page:-

<apex:page docType="html-5.0">
  <apex:includeLightning />
  <div id="lightning"/>
    <script>
    //Get the parameter named msg
    var msg = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.msg}";
    // If msg is null, find it parsing the page URL
    if (msg== null || msg=="") {
        var urlEnc=window.location.href;
        var splitted1 = urlEnc.split('=');
       var splitted=splitted1[2].split('&');
        msg=splitted[0];
        
        
    }
    //Create the Lighting Component inside the VisualForcePage
    $Lightning.use("c:YOUR AURA APP NAME", function() {
       
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:YOUR LWC NAME",{"recordId" : msg},"lightning",
          function(cmp) {
              
          });      
        });
    </script>
    </apex:page>

step 3: create tab for this vf page 

step 4: enable checkbox in vf page settings 

step 5: inside field service mobile settings create an app

 extension choose type as lightning app and provide launch value as "tabname?msg={!Id}" 

step 6:now just use @api recordId to fetch the record id of current page
```